# Running JQuery Async - Not interrupting site load

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, asynchronous

I have the following code. It slows my site down - I know because when I comment it out it cuts around 2 seconds of the load time. How can I tell jquery (I'm using jquery) to load this whenever it has time? there is no rush... anytime is fine so long as it doesn't impact the site load:

```
<div id="indexButtonFacebookDIV" class="indexFooterButtonsDIV">
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=192869610731913";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>    
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo "$index->facebook\n";?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
</div>

<div id="indexButtonGooglePlusDIV" class="indexFooterButtonsDIV">
  <div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-annotation="none"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
  </script>
</div>

<div id="indexButtonTwitterDIV" class="indexFooterButtonsDIV">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php echo "$index->twitter\n";?>" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> 
</div>
```

I tried using head.js script but I couldn't get it to async the load...

thankyou

Comment: You can put all the script tags at the end of the body tag. So the site is more "responsive", in quotes because it's just an illusion. But the buttons will still take its sweet time loading. Also if you've disabled caching on your browser, remember most users will not have that disabled so the scripts will be cached and hence load *slightly* faster

Answer (score 0):

I would make a separate social.js script with all the source you've shown. Go through this source and everywhere you see create for js element make it async like google+ already does (this should not influence any button behaviour).

Then at the end of the body insert script tag

```
<script src="social.js" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
```

Oh, and btw keep the html part of the source where it is, just pluck the scripts out...

So, social.js would look like this:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

    js.async = true;

    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=192869610731913";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

(function() {
      var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
      po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();

!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;  js.async = true; js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```